# Unable to acess Keycloak via browser after configuring SSL/TLS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, jboss, keycloak

I currently have an AWS server set up with docker to run the [Keycloak docker container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak#!). For SSL/TLS, there is an AWS loadbalancer configured to point https/443 traffic to the container and have it receive it over 8080, terminating the encryption connection on said load balancer.

When creating the container with the following command, I am able to browse to and log into the keycloak service by browsing to the server's IP address.
`docker run --name keycloak -v keybase-storage -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=TempAdminPassword jboss/keycloak` However if I try to log into the server by browsing to the URL, I am redirected to the url `http://default-host:8080/auth/admin/` and the browser showing a connection error page.

When trying to find a solution to this, I found how to pass java options to the container when it is first run, and using the resources from [this page](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_installation/topics/host.adoc) I used the following command to start the container(URL replaced for privacy concerns)
`docker run --name keycloak -v keybase-storage -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=TempAdminPassword -e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dkeycloak.frontendUrl=https://sso.IntendedURL.com" jboss/keycloak` However this yields the same results when trying to browse to the page.

The main clue I have to go off of right now is this line near the end of the previously shown `docker run command`, which reads as follows:

`19:23:00,039 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'`

What I believe I need to do now is to either change the config of the docker container after it has been created(have been unable to edit files using `docker exec`, so this is less likely) or to pass a java option into the `run` command when the container is first started.

Please let me know if you have any questions or if I can provide any other information.

Thank you.

Environment information:

- Operating system

  - Amazon Linux 2
- Docker version

  - 19.03.13-ce, build 4484c46
- Keycloak version

  - 12.0.1(WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final)

Comment: It's is not obvious what is a problem and what is your AWS configuration. Blind guess (I hope AWS is OK, eg. sec. groups, TLS configs, ALB, ...): read `Enabling proxy address forwarding` section from used Docker image readme.

Comment: It would seem that the solution would have been to set the following tags when first starting/creating the container:

`KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://sso.IntendedURL.com"/auth`
`PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`

That seemed to have worked, letting us into the server and letting us browse around. However when I go to set an email for the admin user account by browsing to the `manage accounts` page, I am again greeted by a page for `https://default-host::8080/auth/realms/master/account` and so on.

Comment: Even I have to same issue, please let me know if you were able to fix the issue in anyway by logging in to the container